# Calling instance method using class definition in Python

Tags: python, class, instance-methods

Lately, I've been studying Python's class instantiation process to really understand what happen *under the hood* when creating a class instance. But, while playing around with test code, I came across something I don't understand.

Consider this dummy class

```
class Foo():

    def test(self):
        print("I'm using test()")
```

Normally, if I wanted to use `Foo.test` *instance method*, I would go and create an instance of `Foo` and call it explicitly like so,

```
foo_inst = Foo()
foo_inst.test()
>>>> I'm using test()
```

But, I found that calling it that way ends up with the same result,

```
Foo.test(Foo)
>>>> I'm using test()
```

Here I don't actually create an instance, but I'm still accessing `Foo`'s instance method. Why and how is this working in the context of Python ? I mean `self` normally refers to the current instance of the class, but I'm not technically creating a class instance in this case.

```
print(Foo()) #This is a Foo object
>>>><__main__.Foo object at ...>
print(Foo) #This is not
>>>> <class '__main__.Foo'>
```

Comment: You could get the same output by doing `Foo.test(None)`. So the argument doesn't necessarily need to be the class the method belongs to.

Comment: Try printing `self` for both cases and you'll see the difference.

Comment: Since your `test` method does not use the `self` argument, it can be anything (or None) as shown above. What you should actually do with such a method is make it a `static` method (does not have a `self` arg).

Comment: Yes, I get it now. Forgot about duck-typing in Python... `self` doesn't need to be of the class type. Thank you all. `Foo` is also an object and this is why it accepts it.

Comment: @abccd Will do thanks for the insight.

Comment: @scharette great, upvoted. Btw, you can also accept your answer :) you might also mention given `inst = Foo()`: `inst.test()` is equivalent to `Foo.test(inst)`

Comment: @abccd Thanks appreciated. Also, one can only accept his answer after a specific amount of time. If ever no better answers are provided until then, I will accept it for completeness purposes.

Answer (score 2):

Props to everyone that led me there in the comments section.

---

The answer to this question rely on two fundamentals of Python:

1. Duck-typing
2. Everything is an object

Indeed, even if `self` is Python's idiom to reference the current class instance, you technically can pass whatever object you want because of how Python handle typing.

Now, the other confusion that brought me here is that I wasn't creating an object in my second example. But, the thing is, `Foo` is already an object internally.

This can be tested empirically like so,

```
print(type(Foo))
<class 'type'>
```

So, we now know that `Foo` is an instance of class `type` and therefore can be passed as `self` even though it is  not an *instance* of itself.

Basically, if I were to manipulate `self` as if it was a `Foo` object in my `test` method, I would have problem when calling it like my second example.

Answer (score 2):

A few notes on your question (and answer). First, everything is, really an object. Even a class is an object, so, there is the class of the class (called *metaclass*) which is `type` in this case.

Second, more relevant to your case. Methods are, more or less, *class*, not *instance* attributes. In python, when you have an object `obj`, instance of `Class`, and you access `obj.x`, python first looks into `obj`, and then into `Class`. That's what happens when you access a method from an instance, they are just special class attributes, so they can be access from both instance and class. And, since you are not using any instance attributes of the `self` that should be passed to `test(self)` function, the object that is passed is irrelevant.

To understand that in depth, you should read about, *descriptor protocol*, if you are not familiar with it. It explains a lot about how things work in python. It allows python classes and objects to be essentially dictionaries, with some special attributes (very similar to javascript objects and methods)

Regarding the class instantiation, see about `__new__` and *metaclasses*.